# Capturar error a la hora de salvar datos en Cloud Firestore

Tags: angular, firebase

Me gustaría poder "capturar" los errores a la hora de actualizar, agregar o borrar datos en Cloud Firestore. Lo intento hacer con un "then/catch".

Tengo la aplicación en angular corriendo en mi PC local que se conecta con los servidores de "Cloud Firestore". Hago una prueba de desconectar mi PC de la red, con lo cual se desconecta de Cloud Firestore, me gustaría poder capturar el error de alguna forma con un then/catch.

```js
 editarAutor(Autor: ShirtId)
   {
      let identificador= Autor.id;
      let nuevoValor = {
        edad: Autor.edad,
        nombre_autor: Autor.nombre_autor,
        idtime: Autor.idtime
      }
      return this.shirtCollection.doc(identificador).update(nuevoValor).then(res=>{ 
        alert("guardado!!!");
      }).catch(err=>{
        alert(err);
      });
   }
```

Si desconecto la red la librería "angularfire" graba los datos en local y cuando recupera la conexión los guarda en Cloud Firestore. Pero yo quiero que si en ese momento no hay conexión salte un el "alert" del "catch". Pero no salta nada. Cómo puedo controlar esos errores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que para el SDK de firebase, estar desconectado o desconectarse de internet no es un error como tal, entonces no lo muestra porque para el SDK todo esta bien, lo que podrías hacer es verificar la conexión a internet antes de actualizar el documento, con la propiedad:

```
window.navigator.onLine
```

Aunque talvez hay una forma de deshabilitar el modo offline de firebase y que detecte eso como un error, si encuentro algo te lo hago saber.

Comment: Ok, es lo que me temía. Quizá pueda chequear constantemente esa propiedad y mostrar un mensaje en plan "No hay conexión, los datos se guardarán de forma automática cuando se restablezca lka conexión"